# How I can set "Display Product Options In" via Magento2 Api?

Tags: product, api

does anyone know if you can set this option via Magento API

[image: Magento Backend]

I couldn't find anything in the documentation, and I'm too unable to find it in the source code

https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/admin-rest-api.html#tag/products

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution

> ```
>   {
>       "attribute_code": "options_container", //
>       "value": "container2"
>   },
> ```

container1=Product info column

container2=Block after info column